# Can proc summary in SAS analyze more than one variables at a time?

Tags: sas, summary

If I am interested in median of multiple variables (var1, var2, var3), do I have to analyze them one by one?

```
proc summary data=data median nway;
var var1;
class c1 c2 c3;
output out=medians(drop=_:) median=var1_median;
run;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, add them to the VAR list, note the `<s>` in the documentation which indicates it can handle multiple variables. You can also use shortcut [variable lists](https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2018/05/29/6-easy-ways-to-specify-a-list-of-variables-in-sas.html). The documentation has an [example](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/proc/n01kt03q5ggzgkn18we7i8i9ixie.htm).

> VAR variable(s) </ WEIGHT=weight-variable>;

MEANS and SUMMARY procs are fairly interchangeable and MEANS is slightly better documented. In fact the SUMMARY VARS documentation links back to the MEANS proc.

```
proc summary data=data median nway;
var var1 var2 var3-var8 var11--var14;
class c1 c2 c3;
output out=medians(drop=_:) median= / autoname;
*if no autoname option;
*output out=medians(drop = _:) median = var1_median var2_median
var3_median ...... ;
run;
```

If you are doing multiple variables at once, look at the AUTONAME/AUTOLABEL options as well as the [STACKODS option](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/proc/p17h6q7ygvkl1sn13qzf947dundi.htm) to control your output.

Doc references:
[Summary docs](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/proc/p1mq7x66t83ypqn1goff48xzzqyv.htm)

[Means doc](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/proc/p12n9rrav4byvzn1b9wj26dcoq9l.htm)

Comment: thanks a lot. I was stuck at the autoname part and was not sure how to output for the two variables.

Comment: Autoname is a good option but you would just list the names as well. Will edit answer to include that example.

Comment: I see. thanks for adding the other option! autoname works for me too.

Answer (score 1):

Include them in the VAR statement. To write the results to result dataset make sure you either list the same number of names.

```
var var1 var2 ;
output out=medians medians=median_var1 median_var2 ;
```

Or no names, in which case they will use the original names.

```
output out=medians medians= ;
```

You can also add the autoname option.  That is usefull if you need names for other statistics.

```
output out=stats min= max= mean= medians= / autoname ;
```